# Why element's dimensions computed value differs from what's shown in devtools tooltip?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In chrome's dev tools, the value shown in tooltip over the element's for dimensions (width, height) differs from what's shown in the computed value figure as shown in the screenshot. Why ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The box model is showing the dimensions of the element that you've selected in the **DOM Tree**. The tooltip shows you the dimensions of whatever element you're currently hovering over. So the tooltip is probably showing the dimensions of a different element than the one in the box model.